# Configuring AWS Transfer For SFTP to be only accessible for certain IP Addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, sftp, transfer

I have setup an AWS Transfer for SFTP Server, and would like it to only be accessed from Listed IP Addresses. Currently this is working fine when the Endpoint is set to "Public" and have the Authentication Keys setup. I would like to set this up using a "VPC" Endpoint, any help will be appreciated. I have created and Endpoint VPC and have setup the subnets to access the internet. I have then added the IP Address in the "Network ACL" to ALLOW or DENY, but this doesn't work.

Please advice any further options

Comment: Hi, can you tell how you managed the IP Restriction into Public Endpoint, I need to perform that but I am not able to restrict my S3 bucket to some specific IPs.? how you are managing the SFTP Access Control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you switch to VPC Endpoint, you need to create an endpoint for it.

And when you create an endpoint, it requires you to specify the VPC & Subnets & Security Groups.

So in order to allow a **set of specific ip addresses**, you need to **whitelist** them in those **Security Groups**.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I have done, but doesnt seem to work for the SFTP server, I have the same with an EC2 in the VPC and that works fine. I suppose it will be using the same Authentication key that was used when setup using the PUBLIC end point. When I try connecting using WINSCP connecting to the EndPoint I get a message "Server Refused Key"

Comment: For Test Purposes I have not added any Security Group Rules or Network ACLS just to make sure it works.

Comment: Is there any special IP Address range you need to use for the subnets, I am using the default ones that come when the VPC was created

Answer (score 2):

AWS has just added the ability to whitelist IP Addresses for their AWS SFTP service. See the following blog article and documentation how to configure the following:

- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/aws-transfer-for-sftp-supports-vpc-security-groups-and-elastic-ip-addresses/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/create-sftp-server-in-vpc.html#create-internet-facing-endpoint